# Design Patterns for SqlConnection, connection pooling and unit of works

Tags: c#, asp.net, sql-server, design-patterns, unit-of-work

It is clear that SqlConnections are pooled, so the `using` keyword seems perfect and this is the approach I always used and seen used.

For example...

```
public List<string> MyQuery()
{
    List<string> list = new List<string>();
    using (SqlConnection conn = new SqlConnection(connectionString))
    {
        conn.Open();
        // do some stuff with connection, process the resultset and fill the list.
    }
    return list;
}
```

The question is : with several queries for a webpage, is better to create the connection each time or to share the connection between queries, sharing it for an unit of work?

The performances will be much greater or is just a premature unnecessary microoptimization?

Is really important to close every connection as soon as possible or is better to try to pack the queries all together in an unit of work?

An example of an unit of work could be for example...

```
List<string> list1, list2;
string myvalue1, string myvalue2;

using (SqlConnection conn = new SqlConnection(connection))
{
    list1 = MyQuery1(conn);
    list2 = MyQuery2(conn);
    myvalue1 = MyQuery3(conn);
    myvalue2 = MyQuery4(conn);
}
```

This can happens during page load where multiple data should be get from database.

Comment: The general guideline is to close the connection a.s.a.p. If all operations inside the unit of work however, have to be executed inside a single database transaction, then you have no choice: you need to use a single connection and leave it open.

Comment: Yes I understood the point, and is also the easiest way to use connections, so I'm quite happy about this.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Note that with connection pooling, you actually are not creating new connections with each 'new'... you are generally just getting one back from the pool.

Therefore, you should *always* open connections as late as you can, and close them as early as you can.

If a set of commands needs to be part of one transaction, then it needs to be done together. But beyond that, I think you should *always* close when you are done, and get a new one.

Even if you have no other code running between those commands... what if a thread context switch happens in between? Your connection object is needlessly open, doing nothing, waiting to get control back.

If you had closed it, it could have gone back to the pool.

Answer (score 2):

In my opinion if you already have a few queries which are ready to be executed then using a single connection for executing multiple queries is fine.

It is not recommended to keep the connection open if you will have some queries in near future which you want to execute through already open connection. In this case it is recommended to close the connection as soon as possible and for execution of future queries make a new connection

Comment: I take a more strict approach for this: Always close when done with one transaction. See my answer for more.

Answer (score 2):

There's good link from Microsoft http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms971481.aspx , "Using Connections" part.

Its recommended to always close a connection after its use in order for it to be returned to the connection pool.